# do I still need to file.close() when dumping a pickle in one line?

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I currently dump pickles like so:

```
f = open("objectname.p","w")

pickle.dump(objectname,f)

f.close()
```

However, to make for a neat code-snippet in my text editor I want to keep things in one line. I am tempted to:

```
pickle.dump(objectname,open("objectname.p","w"))
```

My question is, will I still need to `f.close()` the file object? and if so, how? (notice I have no variable assigned to the fileobject I opened).

Reasons for YES: `f.close()` exists

Reasons for NO: `objectname = pickle.load(open("objectname.p","r"))` is a recommended way of loading pickle objects as stated in the [pickle python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)

[image]

**There is not a related question matching both "pickle" and "file" that is a duplicate of this. I could not search a solution given my limited vocabulary**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pickling is unrelated to the opening and closing of the file. It only says something about the contents of the file. Hence, in your one-liner the file is opened but not closed.

As such, it's better to do:

```
with open("objectname.p","w") as f:
    pickle.dump(objectname, f)
```

This uses the [with statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) with ensures that at the end of the block it'll call `f.close()` automatically. You're using Python 2.7 and this is supported in that Python version.

Comment: 1 for a nearly one-line answer, I'll just wait a bit before accepting in case there is still a one-line solution

Comment: A one-line solution isn't necessarily better as clarity tends to go down. Also, other than merging lines together, there isn't a one-line solution for this.

Comment: You should probably also use binary mode as per suggestion to be safe! https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle


with open("objectname.p","wb") as f